# How to create an interface for any service in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, interface

I want all the `Service` classes in my backend to have CRUD methods.

For that purpose, I thought of creating an interface:

```java
public interface ServiceCRUD {

    public Object save(Object object);
...
}
```

And then on my service, implement it:

```java
@Service
public class SampleService implements ServiceCRUD {
    @Autowired
    private SampleRepository repository;

    @Override
    public Sample save(Sample sample) {
        return repository.save(sample);
    }

...
}
```

I haven't touched Java in a while, but if I recall correctly, every object extend `Object`, so why is it that I can't use Object to have the service accept all the entities I might have?

Best regards

Comment: Every class extends Object. That doesn't mean List<Sample> extends List<Object>

Comment: I have the same problem on the method without the list

Comment: Your interface says "I am a thing which can accept any Object", your specific implementation says "I am a thing which accepts only Samples". So your implementation does not adhere to the interface

Comment: Suppose I have `ServiceCRUD service = new SampleService(...);` I should be able to call `.save("hello world")`. That's what the interface says. The actual implementation does not support that

Comment: Ok, I see the problem. So, how can I solve it?

Comment: This is what generics are for. `interface ServiceCRUD<T>`, `T save(T object);` and `SampleService implements ServiceCRUD<Sample>`

Comment: Are you thinking about generics @LuisFernandez

Comment: But also, Spring already declares the [`Repository` interface (and `CrudInterface` etc.)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) which is basically for an identical purpose. I would start by making sure that you don't want to use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve such scenario using `Generics`

```
interface ServiceCRUD {

    public < E > void save(E object);
}


class Sample {
    private String name = "Joe";

   
   @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "hello"+name;
    }
}

class SampleService implements ServiceCRUD {


    @Override
    public < Sample > void save(Sample sample) {
        System.out.print(sample.toString());
    }


}



public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SampleService().save(new Sample());

    }
}
```

This is just an example ,you can extend it as per your use case.
See working [here](https://replit.com/join/lufmnswi-shubhamdixit863)

Answer (score 0):

Your interface declares that one is possible to save `Object`, i. e. any object. But your implementation declares that it cat get only `Sample`, that's why you get compilation error.
You should go with genetic and let each implementation to declare what kind of object it can deal with. I strongly suggest to have a look at spring data project. It will save you a lot if time